# InfluxDB 2 / influxdb-client-java: Long data is written but String value is read. ClassCastException occurred

Tags: java, influxdb, influxdb-2

InfluxDB v2.5.1

influxdb-client-java 6.7.0

Java POJO

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Measurement(name = "my_measurement")
public class MyMeasurement {

    @Column(timestamp = true)
    private Instant time;

    @Column(name = "my_tag", tag = true)
    private Long myTag;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private Integer value;

}
```

Write

```java
influxDBClient.getWriteApiBlocking().writeMeasurements(WritePrecision.NS,
        IntStream.range(0, 1000)
                .mapToObj(i -> MyMeasurement.builder()
                        .time(Instant.now())
                        .myTag(Math.abs(new Random().nextLong()))
                        .value(Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()))
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Read

```java
influxDBClient.getQueryApi()
    .query("from(bucket: \"mybucket\") |> range(start: -1d) |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"my_measurement\")", MyMeasurement.class);
```

The reading statement throws `InfluxException`

```
com.influxdb.exceptions.InfluxException: Class 'MyMeasurement' field 'myTag' was defined with a different field type and caused a ClassCastException. The correct type is 'java.lang.String' (current field value: '1000816197908726879').
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all tag in influxdb always is string [link](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.5/reference/glossary/#tag-value)
2. Secondly when you get it from influx using influx-client it get it from influxdb as a String and cannot cast to Long.
   (because under hood java influx client uses `long.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType))` and String is not assiganble for Long.
   Possible solution is to use `String` for tags in your POJO.